# how to change the color of subplot datafile in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

**In Short:**

I want to change the color of **blue marker** in the graph. So that I can do comparison with other plots easily.
You can download the data files and script [from this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ybte7hfs10i6e60/plot.tar.gz?dl=1)

---

**Problem Explanation**

I have two data files, full.dat and part.dat(Note: part.dat is also there in full.dat).

I got the plotting scripts from the internet, and it is working very well. But as a noob in Python and Matplotlib, I am facing difficulties in changing the color of part.dat.
Please see the graph first, then the following scripts.

**Script-1: Function and definitions: let's say: "func.py"**

```
# This was written by Levi Lentz for the Kolpak Group at MIT
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gs
import sys

#This function extracts the high symmetry points from the output of bandx.out
def Symmetries(fstring):
  f = open(fstring,'r')
  x = np.zeros(0)
  for i in f:
    if "high-symmetry" in i:
      x = np.append(x,float(i.split()[-1]))
  f.close()
  return x
# This function takes in the datafile, the fermi energy, the symmetry file, a subplot, and the label
# It then extracts the band data, and plots the bands, the fermi energy in red, and the high symmetry points
def bndplot(datafile_full,datafile,fermi,symmetryfile,subplot,**kwargs):

  if 'shift_fermi' in kwargs:
    bool_shift_efermi = kwargs['shift_fermi']
  else:
    bool_shift_efermi = 0
  if 'color' in kwargs:
    color_bnd=kwargs['color']
  else:
    color_bnd='black'
  if 'linestyle' in kwargs:
    line_bnd=kwargs['linestyle']
  else:
    line_bnd='solid'

  z = np.loadtxt(datafile_full) #This loads the full.dat file
  x = np.unique(z[:,0]) #This is all the unique x-points
  [a,b,w]=np.loadtxt(datafile,unpack=True) #Weight
  bands = []
  bndl = len(z[z[:,0]==x[1]]) #This gives the number of bands in the calculation
  Fermi = float(fermi)
  if bool_shift_efermi:
    fermi_shift=Fermi
  else:
    fermi_shift=0
  axis = [min(x),max(x)]
  for i in range(0,bndl):
    bands.append(np.zeros([len(x),2])) #This is where we storre the bands
  for i in range(0,len(x)):
    sel = z[z[:,0] == x[i]]  #Here is the energies for a given x
    test = []
    for j in range(0,bndl): #This separates it out into a single band
      bands[j][i][0] = x[i]
      #bands[j][i][1] = np.multiply(sel[j][1],13.605698066)
      bands[j][i][1] = sel[j][1]
      #Here we plots the bands
  for i in bands:
    subplot.plot(i[:,0],i[:,1]-fermi_shift,color=color_bnd,linestyle=line_bnd, linewidth=0.7,alpha=0.5)
# plt.scatter(a,b-fermi_shift,c=w,cmap='viridis',alpha=0.5)
# plt.colorbar()
  if 'legend' in kwargs:
    #empty plot to generate legend
    subplot.plot([None],[None],color=color_bnd,linestyle=line_bnd,label=kwargs['legend'])
  temp = Symmetries(symmetryfile)
  for j in temp: #This is the high symmetry lines
    x1 = [j,j]
    subplot.axvline(x=j,linestyle='dashed',color='black',alpha=0.75)
  subplot.plot([min(x),max(x)],[Fermi-fermi_shift,Fermi-fermi_shift],color='red',linestyle='dotted')
  subplot.set_xticks(temp)
  subplot.set_xticklabels([])
  if 'name_k_points' in kwargs:
    if len(kwargs['name_k_points'])==len(temp):
      subplot.set_xticklabels(kwargs['name_k_points'])
  if 'range' in kwargs:
    range_plot=kwargs['range']
    subplot.set_ylim([range_plot[0],range_plot[1]])
  subplot.set_xlim([axis[0],axis[1]])
  subplot.set_xlabel('k')
  subplot.set_ylabel('E-E$_f$')
  plt.scatter(a,b-fermi_shift,s=70*np.array(w))
  if 'legend' in kwargs:
      plt.legend()
```

**script-2 Plotting script: let's say: "plot.py"**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from func import *
El='el'
orb='orb'
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]=(4,15)
datafile_full='bands.dat.gnu'
#datafile=El+'_'+orb+'.dat.all'
datafile=El+'_'+orb+'.dat.all'
fermi = 10.2382
symmetryfile='band.out'
bool_shift_efermi= True
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#bndplot(datafile,fermi,symmetryfile,ax)
bndplot(datafile_full,datafile,fermi,symmetryfile,ax,shift_fermi=1,color='black',linestyle='solid',name_k_points=['K','G','M','K','H','A','L','H'], legend=El+', '+orb+'-orbital')

#ax.set_ylim(-5,5)
ax.set_ylim(-10,12)
fig.set_figheight(6)
fig.set_figwidth(4)

plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22})
fig.savefig("el-orb.eps")
plt.show()
```

In script-2, there is an option to change the color, however I want to change the color of **blue marker/solid-circles**(please see the graph) so that I can compare with other graphs.
Whenever I change the color, it changes the line color only.
Please help me out I am trying to understand Matplotlib uses and examples from past few hrs However as a noob I was not able to figure out how to do.

[image: graph]

Comment: You could try `ax.plot(...., mfc='purple')` to change the "marker face color". Similarly, there is `mec=...` to change the "marker edge color".

Comment: @JohanC thanks a lot for your reply.
I tried however, It didn't work.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ybte7hfs10i6e60/plot.tar.gz?dl=1
the dir having everything. after running the plot script it also opens gui to change few things. but still I m not able to change that blue color.